# What does the css selector ':' and '::'? What is the difference between them?

Tags: css

What does the css selector ':' and '::'? What is the difference between them? Are both browser compatible? If not, for cross browser perspective, which one we should use?

Comment: They don't mean anything by themselves, but they can mean different things depending on context. You should provide this context.

Answer (score 0):

`:` is the prefix for the pseudo-classes where as `::` is the prefix for the pseudo-elements.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors